# ProcessData Node.js stin/stdout) issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, stdin

Having a bit of trouble understanding how to run my code using a ProcessData wrapping function on hackerrank (node.js). It seems I can't drop a function with the parameters I have in the ProcessData wrapper without getting back ~no response on stdout~. How do I pass their input (a string of integers) in to my function and get a response of some sort so I can debug? Help would definitely be appreciated. Please see my function, the coding environment, the input & expected output below.  Thanks!

For reference: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation

```
    /*

     Input Format

    The first line contains two space-separated integers 
denoting the respective values of  (the number of integers) 
and  (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
    The second line contains  space-separated integers 
describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

    */

/*Environment with my code, below (how do I pass input as an argument to this function?? 
console.log or return the data, and get a response for debugging?)*/

function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    var rotate = function(num,turns,ar){
    var store = ar.slice(0, turns);
    for(var i=0; i<store.length; i++){
        ar.shift();
        ar.push(store[i]);
    }
    return ar;
};
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `process.stdout.write`. For example:

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    process.stdout.write('5 1 2 3 4');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks @stdob-- .. Thanks, I'm definitely getting something, but still a bit lost. Using your suggestion, how would I go about passing the input 5 4
1 2 3 4 5 (5 being the number of integers in the array, 4 being the number of rotations, and 1,2,3,4,5 - on a new line -  supposed to be used as the array itself) ??

Comment: You need split `input` by newline: `input.split(/\r|\n/)`. Then split every line by whitespace: `line.split(/\s+/)`.

Answer (score 0):

instead use 
let input = 4; //4 is an integer variable

function processData(input) {

//before outputing the integre you need to convert it to string using toString();

```
process.stdout.write(input.toString().trim());
```

}

//Note the output  is converted to string 
Output: 4